# How does For-Range works in golang with assembly codes?

Tags: for-loop, go, assembly

I'm confused by the pointer usage within for-range in golang when the source code is assembled. For example, we know the variable *value* below will always be in the same memory address, and the corresponding assembly codes shows the same logic.

```
// Source Code
func main() {
a := []int{1, 3, 5}

    for _, value := range a {
        foo(&value)
    }

}

func foo(a *int) int {
b := *a * 42
fmt.Println(b)
return b
}

// Assembly Code
"".main STEXT size=126 args=0x0 locals=0x38 funcid=0x0
0x0000 00000 (main.go:15)       TEXT    "".main(SB), ABIInternal, $56-0
0x0000 00000 (main.go:15)       CMPQ    SP, 16(R14)
0x0004 00004 (main.go:15)       PCDATA  $0, $-2
0x0004 00004 (main.go:15)       JLS     119
0x0006 00006 (main.go:15)       PCDATA  $0, $-1
0x0006 00006 (main.go:15)       SUBQ    $56, SP
0x000a 00010 (main.go:15)       MOVQ    BP, 48(SP)
0x000f 00015 (main.go:15)       LEAQ    48(SP), BP
0x0014 00020 (main.go:15)       FUNCDATA        $0, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
0x0014 00020 (main.go:15)       FUNCDATA        $1, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
0x0014 00020 (main.go:16)       MOVQ    $0, ""..autotmp_4+24(SP)
0x001d 00029 (main.go:16)       LEAQ    ""..autotmp_4+32(SP), CX
0x0022 00034 (main.go:16)       MOVUPS  X15, (CX)
0x0026 00038 (main.go:16)       MOVQ    $1, ""..autotmp_4+24(SP)
0x002f 00047 (main.go:16)       MOVQ    $3, ""..autotmp_4+32(SP)
0x0038 00056 (main.go:16)       MOVQ    $5, ""..autotmp_4+40(SP)
0x0041 00065 (main.go:16)       XORL    AX, AX
0x0043 00067 (main.go:18)       JMP     103
0x0045 00069 (main.go:18)       MOVQ    AX, ""..autotmp_10+16(SP)
0x004a 00074 (main.go:18)       MOVQ    ""..autotmp_4+24(SP)(AX\*8), CX
0x004f 00079 (main.go:18)       MOVQ    CX, "".value+8(SP)
0x0054 00084 (main.go:19)       LEAQ    "".value+8(SP), AX        // Here we see we always use "".value+8(SP) as the argument into foo()
0x0059 00089 (main.go:19)       PCDATA  $1, $0
0x0059 00089 (main.go:19)       CALL    "".foo(SB)
0x005e 00094 (main.go:18)       MOVQ    ""..autotmp_10+16(SP), CX
0x0063 00099 (main.go:18)       LEAQ    1(CX), AX
0x0067 00103 (main.go:18)       CMPQ    AX, $3
0x006b 00107 (main.go:18)       JLT     69
0x006d 00109 (main.go:21)       PCDATA  $1, $-1
0x006d 00109 (main.go:21)       MOVQ    48(SP), BP
0x0072 00114 (main.go:21)       ADDQ    $56, SP
0x0076 00118 (main.go:21)       RET
0x0077 00119 (main.go:21)       NOP
0x0077 00119 (main.go:15)       PCDATA  $1, $-1
0x0077 00119 (main.go:15)       PCDATA  $0, $-2
0x0077 00119 (main.go:15)       CALL    runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)
0x007c 00124 (main.go:15)       PCDATA  $0, $-1
0x007c 00124 (main.go:15)       JMP     0
0x0000 49 3b 66 10 76 71 48 83 ec 38 48 89 6c 24 30 48  I;f.vqH..8H.l$0H
0x0010 8d 6c 24 30 48 c7 44 24 18 00 00 00 00 48 8d 4c  .l$0H.D$.....H.L
0x0020 24 20 44 0f 11 39 48 c7 44 24 18 01 00 00 00 48  $ D..9H.D$.....H
0x0030 c7 44 24 20 03 00 00 00 48 c7 44 24 28 05 00 00  .D$ ....H.D$(...
0x0040 00 31 c0 eb 22 48 89 44 24 10 48 8b 4c c4 18 48  .1.."H.D$.H.L..H
0x0050 89 4c 24 08 48 8d 44 24 08 e8 00 00 00 00 48 8b  .L$.H.D$......H.
0x0060 4c 24 10 48 8d 41 01 48 83 f8 03 7c d8 48 8b 6c  L$.H.A.H...|.H.l
0x0070 24 30 48 83 c4 38 c3 e8 00 00 00 00 eb 82        $0H..8........
rel 90+4 t=7 "".foo+0
rel 120+4 t=7 runtime.morestack_noctxt+0
```

However, when I change the source code and try to see what changes in the assembly codes, I found nothing changed.

```
// Changed Source Code
func main() {
a := []int{1, 3, 5}

    for _, value := range a {
        v := value
        foo(&v)
    }

}

func foo(a *int) int {
b := *a * 42
fmt.Println(b)
return b
}

// Changed Assembly Code
"".main STEXT size=126 args=0x0 locals=0x38 funcid=0x0
0x0000 00000 (main.go:15)       TEXT    "".main(SB), ABIInternal, $56-0
0x0000 00000 (main.go:15)       CMPQ    SP, 16(R14)
0x0004 00004 (main.go:15)       PCDATA  $0, $-2
0x0004 00004 (main.go:15)       JLS     119
0x0006 00006 (main.go:15)       PCDATA  $0, $-1
0x0006 00006 (main.go:15)       SUBQ    $56, SP
0x000a 00010 (main.go:15)       MOVQ    BP, 48(SP)
0x000f 00015 (main.go:15)       LEAQ    48(SP), BP
0x0014 00020 (main.go:15)       FUNCDATA        $0, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
0x0014 00020 (main.go:15)       FUNCDATA        $1, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
0x0014 00020 (main.go:16)       MOVQ    $0, ""..autotmp_5+24(SP)
0x001d 00029 (main.go:16)       LEAQ    ""..autotmp_5+32(SP), CX
0x0022 00034 (main.go:16)       MOVUPS  X15, (CX)
0x0026 00038 (main.go:16)       MOVQ    $1, ""..autotmp_5+24(SP)
0x002f 00047 (main.go:16)       MOVQ    $3, ""..autotmp_5+32(SP)
0x0038 00056 (main.go:16)       MOVQ    $5, ""..autotmp_5+40(SP)
0x0041 00065 (main.go:16)       XORL    AX, AX
0x0043 00067 (main.go:18)       JMP     103
0x0045 00069 (main.go:18)       MOVQ    AX, ""..autotmp_11+16(SP)
0x004a 00074 (main.go:18)       MOVQ    ""..autotmp_5+24(SP)(AX\*8), CX
0x004f 00079 (main.go:19)       MOVQ    CX, "".v+8(SP)
0x0054 00084 (main.go:20)       LEAQ    "".v+8(SP), AX    // Here we see the logic of argument is the same as above. This makes me confused.
0x0059 00089 (main.go:20)       PCDATA  $1, $0
0x0059 00089 (main.go:20)       CALL    "".foo(SB)
0x005e 00094 (main.go:18)       MOVQ    ""..autotmp_11+16(SP), CX
0x0063 00099 (main.go:18)       LEAQ    1(CX), AX
0x0067 00103 (main.go:18)       CMPQ    AX, $3
0x006b 00107 (main.go:18)       JLT     69
0x006d 00109 (main.go:22)       PCDATA  $1, $-1
0x006d 00109 (main.go:22)       MOVQ    48(SP), BP
0x0072 00114 (main.go:22)       ADDQ    $56, SP
0x0076 00118 (main.go:22)       RET
0x0077 00119 (main.go:22)       NOP
0x0077 00119 (main.go:15)       PCDATA  $1, $-1
0x0077 00119 (main.go:15)       PCDATA  $0, $-2
0x0077 00119 (main.go:15)       CALL    runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)
0x007c 00124 (main.go:15)       PCDATA  $0, $-1
0x007c 00124 (main.go:15)       JMP     0
0x0000 49 3b 66 10 76 71 48 83 ec 38 48 89 6c 24 30 48  I;f.vqH..8H.l$0H
0x0010 8d 6c 24 30 48 c7 44 24 18 00 00 00 00 48 8d 4c  .l$0H.D$.....H.L
0x0020 24 20 44 0f 11 39 48 c7 44 24 18 01 00 00 00 48  $ D..9H.D$.....H
0x0030 c7 44 24 20 03 00 00 00 48 c7 44 24 28 05 00 00  .D$ ....H.D$(...
0x0040 00 31 c0 eb 22 48 89 44 24 10 48 8b 4c c4 18 48  .1.."H.D$.H.L..H
0x0050 89 4c 24 08 48 8d 44 24 08 e8 00 00 00 00 48 8b  .L$.H.D$......H.
0x0060 4c 24 10 48 8d 41 01 48 83 f8 03 7c d8 48 8b 6c  L$.H.A.H...|.H.l
0x0070 24 30 48 83 c4 38 c3 e8 00 00 00 00 eb 82        $0H..8........
rel 90+4 t=7 "".foo+0
rel 120+4 t=7 runtime.morestack_noctxt+0
```

So how does the local variable `v` influence the for-range?

Just as the details above, I think the assembly code should show how the introduce of new local variable works, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several points.

[The spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_statements) only says the following on your case:

> The iteration variables may be declared <…> using a form of short variable declaration (`:=`). In this case <…>; they are re-used in each iteration.

And that is all: it says there will be variables, and they will be
re-used. The latter point means that, say, if you create a closure–an anonymous function, using a function literal,–which will close over one or more iteration variables, and would return/save it somewhere and call after the loop ends *or concurrently* with the loop (say, in a separate goroutine), that closure will access those very same variables each iteration of the loop updated (or is updating).

If you do not do any such fancy stuff–say, only read from those variables in the loop body's code, the fact these variables are re-used is irrelevant.

Let's reiterate: the spec does not give any guarantees about the memory addresses of the iteration variables.

Why this matters? Because the compiler is free to generate any code it wishes as long as the result works in a way to follow the spec, and what the compiler does, depends on at least the following:

- Target hardware (`GOARCH`).
- Version *and make* (implementation) of Go. Don't underestimate this one: the spec, for instance, does not define precisely how the GC works, so any make and any version of Go is free to implement moving GC which would move arbitrary variables in memory and update all the pointers pointing at them.
  Currently, popular makes of Go (the one you're supposedly used, and the GCC front-end) do not do that, but nothing prevents them or any other implementation from doing that.

Hence, in the end, you're asking why a particular compiler generates a particularly-looking code, and do not state neither the make of Go, nor its version nor your `GOARCH` (though it could be guessed it's probably `amd64`). Because of this, your question is practically unanswerable, and precise answers to it would not be too useful as they can become obsolete pretty quickly.
Because of that such questions are off-topic on SO.
I've decided to put all this as an answer simply because it's too much for a comment.

---

In your particular case, the compiler might have analyzed the code of `foo` and saw that it does not update the variable passed to it via the pointer argument and–which is more important–does not pass it further down the call stack. Since nothing else is done with `v` in the loop body, the compiler might have decided that *semantically* `v` can be considered as a mere alias to `variable` and it just skipped creation of that separate variable. I could conjure that if you were to pass pointers to *both* these variables to `foo`, and, say, make it print these addresses, the compiler would be forced to materialize `v`.

Note that the about is just a guess. If you want to know all the details, you can always study how the compiler works (both popular implementations of Go are pieces of F/OSS) and/or instrument its code.

Also note that you can ask the compiler to tell you more about what it does. The most commonly used implementation of Go (dubbed `gc` originally) supports the `-gcflags` command-line parameter in its `go build` and `go install` invocation which passes parameters down to the compiler (see `go tool compile -help`). In particular, its `-m` and `-N` (also `-S` and `-live`) flags may be of interest to play with.

Comment: Thanks kostix! Your guess about the unexpected **foo** assembly codes is right, and by your suggestion I understand how the compiler works when it must create a new object.